# My SSL cert chain is missing a subject

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm trying to set up LDAP authentication at a client (I'll call them Example, Inc.).  I've used `openssl s_client` to grab the certificate chain, but I'm still having issues.  When I verify the chain, I get this (ignoring hopefully irrevevant bits):

```
Certificate chain
0 s:
  i:/C=US/DC=com/DC=example/DC=rl/DC=example/O=Example Inc./OU=EXAMPLE/CN=XMPL L3 Low Iss E4 CA
[...]
1 s:/C=US/DC=com/DC=example/DC=rl/DC=example/O=Example Inc./OU=EXAMPLE/CN=XMPL L3 Low Iss E4 CA
  i:/C=US/O=Example Inc./OU=EXAMPLE/CN=XMPL L3 INT Low CA
[...]
2 s:/C=US/O=Example Inc./OU=EXAMPLE/CN=XMPL L3 INT Low CA
  i:/C=US/O=Example Inc./OU=EXAMPLE/CN=Example L3 Root CA
[...]
```

On every web page that I've looked at where someone publishes a certificate chain, the first one (depth 0) has a subject (the s: line).  This doesn't.  Could that be the source of my problem?

Persuant to @ChadSikorra's answer below, I used `openssl x509` to examine all three certificates and look for the word "critical".  I found it in the following places.

The first cert, with the blank subject, (XMPL L3 Low Iss E4 CA) says,

```
X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
    CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
```

The second one, with non-blank subject, (XMPL L3 INT Low CA) says,

```
X509v3 Key Usage: critical
    Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: critical
    DNS:host.example.rl.example.com, DNS:host, DNS:EXAMPLE, DNS:example.rl.example.com, DNS:ldap, DNS:ldap.example.com
```

The third cert (Example L3 Root CA) says,

```
X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
    CA:TRUE
```

Comment: *"I'm still having issues..."* and *"Could that be the source of my problem..."* - you never say what the problems or issues are. Strictly speaking, you don't need a server name in the *Common Name (CN)* of the *Distinguished Name (DN)* (i.e., the Subject DN). The CN is a friendly name and its displayed by tools for the user. I don't recall seeing a missing *DN*, and I'm guessing it is considered malformed because it is effectively a key for the directory lookup. If the server names are in the *Subject Alternative Name (SAN)* then the certificate should validate (some hand waiving).

Comment: I can only say *" I'm guessing it is considered malformed..."* because we don't know what standard you are conforming to in your particular PKI. Since you have the ***`SSL`*** tag, can we assume its PKIX? PKIX is the Internet's PKI, and it is specified by a number of IETF documents. For example, RFCs like [Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Certificate and Certificate Revocation List (CRL) Profile](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) and [Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure: Certification Path Building](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4158.txt).

Comment: I'm not an LDAP guru, I'm just a guy trying to get LDAP authentication working at a customer's site.  I've not done it very many times but when I have, I've not had any issues.  So, I have no idea which standard my PKI conforms to.  I did discover that the customer is using Infoblox DNS, because the manual says, "When using Active Directory with a Linux-based frontend server, the server at the top of the list in /etc/resolv.conf must be the primary Active Directory DNS server" but I don't know if that's helpful.

Comment: To expand a bit, I have a Tomcat web server and I want people to be able to log in using their Windows credentials.  When I try to log in, I get an error about the certificate chain.  After re-reading the manual, I checked my DNS servers and none of them were Windows based.  When I asked, I was told that the client used Infoblox DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty good explanation of the issue you are seeing from 
[Third Party Application Fails Using LDAP over SSL](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/09/16/third-party-application-fails-using-ldap-over-ssl/):

> The following issue is one that I have seen come up from time to time
>   and can be a challenge for IT administrators who are trying to use the
>   built in Version 2 Domain Controller Authentication template in their
>   environment. The concern may be seen when folks used a version 1
>   certificate in the past but the newer one (version 2) seems to give
>   some unexpected results.
>
> So what’s the problem? Well, if you have a third party application
>   which uses LDAP over SSL to connect to the domain controller it may
>   not work initially using the new version 2 Domain controller
>   Authentication certificate.
>
> So let’s go over the issue in detail. A 3rd party application was
>   making LDAP over SSL connections to the Domain Controllers as part of
>   what it does intentionally.  This was working when the domain
>   controller had a certificate based on the “old style” version 1 Domain
>   Controller template. An Enterprise Certification Authority had issued
>   the certificate. However, the “Domain Controller” certificates have
>   been superseded by certificates based on the “Domain Controller
>   Authentication” certificates which can happen for several reasons that
>   we won’t go into great detail on in this blog post today.  The end
>   result which is seen is that the 3rd party application now fails.
>
> What is the apparent problem? By default, the “Domain Controller
>   Authentication” certificate has a blank subject field and the Subject
>   Alternate Name (SAN) field is marked critical on the “Domain
>   Controller Authentication” certificate. Simply put, some applications
>   cannot use a certificate if the SAN field being marked critical.
>
> Why is this field important? Some applications may have difficulty
>   using the certificate if the SAN field is marked critical and the
>   subject field is blank because of how these fields are checked when
>   deciding whether to use a certificate.

Assuming this is Active Directory anyway. But it would probably be valid elsewhere too. Long story short, the default DC Auth template for the LDAP SSL certificates omits the subject name entirely in favor of filling in the subject alternative names and marking it as critical.

However, I know for a fact that this can lead to issues when using the OpenLDAP/OpenSSL libraries when trying to connect over TLS/SSL. If you're using OpenLDAP you can use `ldap_set_option` with the `LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL` constant and set the value to 7. Then it should tell you exactly what it is tripping over with regards to the certificate.

You could either have them re-issue a new certificate that actually fills in the subject name or (if using OpenLDAP for the library pieces) you could change the `TLS_REQCERT` option to `allow` or `none` (which would unfortunately raise some security concerns...).

Comment: My certs look ok according to the note you referenced.  However, I am using a Java-based OpenLDAP/OpenSSL libraries to connect over TLS/SSL, so your later comment may still apply.  Thanks, I will be digging some more.